# Project based , angular cli + firebase + travis ci configuration error

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, travis-ci

I think there's something wrong with my travis.yml file code.
Even if I changed it couple of times my Travis Cl project gets failed again and again.

## .travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "8.9"

branches:
  only:
    - master

before_script:
  - npm install  firebase-tools
  - npm install  @angular/cli

script:
  - ng build 

after_success:
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

So I think if someone done this configuration might help me.
Thanks,Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right @Sachin, 
There were some errors in your code.
In your third line it should be node_js version 8, and in 10,11 lines it should have -g command.

And in the script also it should have --product.

So after correcting those errors I rewrote the code.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "8"

branches:
  only:
    - master

before_script:
  - npm install -g @angular/cli
  - npm install -g firebase-tools

script:
  - ng build --prod --aot

after_success:
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

**Hope this code might fix you're errors.**
**Cheers.**

Comment: Thnx @Emely, Your code is perfect, It's working fine. And thnx again for the guidance. Cheers.